# Is there a permutation $\sigma(n)$ of $\{0,1,2,\ldots,m-1\},$ such that $\{(n+\sigma(n))\pmod m:0\leq n\leq m-1\}=\{0,1,2,\ldots m-1\}?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, permutations, pigeonhole-principle

> Given $m\in\mathbb{N},$ is there a permutation $\sigma(n)$ of
> $\{0,1,2,\ldots,m-1\},$ such that $\{ (n+\sigma(n))\pmod m: 0\leq n
> \leq m-1 \} = \{0,1,2,\ldots m-1\},\ ?$

Based on computation with Python for low numbers, the answer seems to be, "yes for prime numbers; no for non-primes", although this might not be true as the results of low numbers (up to $m=9$) could be deceptive. However, there is some evidence that the conjecture is true: for $m=3$ there are about $3$ "successes" (successful permutations). For $m=4$ there are no successes. For $m=5$ there are about $10$ successes. For $m=6$ there are no successes. For $m=7$ there are lots of successes. For $m=8$ there are no successes.

Edit: for $m=9$ there are lots of successes, so this suggests the answer is "yes for odd, no for even", rather than "yes for primes", which also matches the current only answer.

Python code for $m=5$:

```
import itertools
length_five_list=[0, 1, 2, 3,4]
permutations_list=list(itertools.permutations(length_five_list))

print(permutations_list)
    
for x in permutations_list:
    current_zip = zip(x,length_five_list)
    sum_list = []
    for y in current_zip:
        sum_list.append(sum(y)%5)
        if set(sum_list) == set(length_five_list):
            print('sum_list=', sum_list)
            print( 'success: permutation was', x)
```

I also have a similar question for $n\sigma(n)$ instead of $n+\sigma(n),$ but let's deal with one question at a time.

Comment: The number of such permutations is given by https://oeis.org/A006717, "Number of ways of arranging 2n+1 nonattacking semi-queens on a (2n+1) X (2n+1) toroidal board."  A "semi-queen" appears to be a chess piece that can move vertically, horizontally, or diagonally but only along one diagonal.  I don't know anything particularly deep about this question - I just brute-forced it for n = 3, 5, 7 and got 3, 15, 133, which was enough to give a match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a permutation exists iff $m$ is odd. For any odd $m$, choose $\sigma(n) = n$. Then $2$ resulting values being congruent to each other means

$$n_1 + \sigma(n_1) \equiv n_2 + \sigma(n_2) \pmod{m} \;\to\; 2(n_1 - n_2) \equiv 0 \pmod{m}$$

Since $m$ is odd, with $0 \le n_1, n_2 \le m - 1 \;\to\; -m \lt n_1 - n_2 \lt m$, then $m\mid n_1 - n_2 \;\to\; n_1 - n_2 = 0 \;\to\; n_1 = n_2$. Thus, all of the modulo values are unique and, by the [Pigeonhole Principle](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), must comprise the values between $0$ and $m - 1$, inclusive.

With $m$ being even, assume such a permutation exists. We then get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}(n+\sigma(n)) & \equiv \sum_{n=0}^{m-1}n \pmod{m} \\
2\left(\frac{(m-1)m}{2}\right) & \equiv \frac{(m-1)m}{2} \pmod{m} \\
(m-1)\left(\frac{m}{2}\right) & \equiv 0 \pmod{m}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

This means $m \mid (m-1)\left(\frac{m}{2}\right)$. However, $\gcd(m-1,m) = 1$ (with $\gcd(m-1,m)=d$, then $d\mid m-1$ and $d\mid m$, so $d\mid(m - (m-1))$, i.e., $d\mid 1$, so $d=1)$. As mentioned in [Adam's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4883903/is-there-a-permutation-sigman-of-0-1-2-ldots-m-1-such-that-n-s#comment10417551_4883914), using the theorem that if $a\mid bc$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $a\mid c$, we get $m \mid \frac{m}{2}$. However, this is not possible. Thus, the assumption that such a permutation exists is false.

Comment: What's the name of the thing you have used in your penultimate sentence? Bezout's identity? Or related?

Comment: @AdamRubinson There are $2$ things I have in my penultimate sentence of "However, since $\gcd(m-1,m) = 1$, then $m \mid \frac{m}{2}$, which is not possible" (note I just corrected it for the $\gcd$ value to be $1$, not $0$), so I'm unsure which one you're referring to. Regardless, I'm unaware of either one having a specific name, but neither is particularly related to Bezout's identity that I can determine offhand.

Comment: Ok then, please can you clearly explain how $\gcd(m-1,m) = 1$ and $(m-1)\left(\frac{m}{2}\right) \equiv 0 \pmod{m} \implies m \mid \frac{m}{2}\ ?$

Comment: @AdamRubinson I have added some more details in my last paragraph to try to address your comment's requests. If there is anything which remains unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Well I already get that $gcd(m-1,m)=1.$ That's obvious. What isn't immediately obvious to me is how you deduce that this implies $m\mid \frac{m}{2}.$ So I think you are using a theorem that, if $a\mid bc$ and $gcd(a,b)=1,$ then $a\mid c.$ Is this right? [It sounds right, but I am unfamiliar with such theorems to be honest. And I reckon there is a slightly more general version of this theorem which is more well-known].

Comment: @AdamRubinson You are correct. I'm using that specific theorem you mentioned (note I'm unaware of it having any specific name, or any more general version of the theorem, including any with its own name) to determine that $m\mid\frac{m}{2}$.

Comment: Ok, thanks.....

Comment: @AdamRubinson You're welcome. Thanks for explaining what you were having difficulties with, as it allowed me to determine how to improve my answer. In particular, I've updated my answer to explicitly mention the theorem you asked about in your comment, i.e., "if $a\mid bc$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $a\mid c$".